# jquery json data autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm facing an issue with jquery autocomplete. I need that after autocompleting the results on click it converts to a link with item.value:

My actual json encode return is:

```
[{value: "34"}, {label: "Producto 12"}]
```

```js
$(function() {
    $("#producto").autocomplete({
        select: function (e, ui) {
            $("#producto").val(ui.item.label);
            window.location.href = item.value;
            return false;
        },

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/vista/autocompletar'); ?>",
                data: request,
                success: function (data) {
                    var ParsedObject = $.parseJSON(data);
                    response($.map(ParsedObject, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                        };

                    }))
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Solution:
Changed the json encode to work like this:
{value: "14", label: "afasdasd"}

And did changed the autocomplete jquery code for this one:

```
    $(function(){
        $("#producto").autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/vista/autocompletar'); ?>",
            minLength: 2,
            select : function(event, ui){
                // convierto en link el resultado y al hacer click me dirija a la vista del producto
                location.href = "<?=base_url()?>index.php/vista/detalle/" + ui.item.value;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), you'll see the correct format is `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`. You need to amend the data structure your `index.php` page is returning.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the php query to work like that and it works like a charm.